# Multiple Value set Name with Index

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm new in iOS and beginner about Programming.

I have some question about programming.

***Problem***

I Have 5 NSMutableArray and I want to add All NSMutableArray to 1 NSMutableArray

Following this Code.

In .h File

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderType1;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderType2;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderType3;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderType4;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderType5;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allData;
```

In .m File

```
    for(int i = 0; i < orderCount; i++)    // orderCount is count of orderType(count = 5)
    {
         // Do something about condition to get Data...
         // ... This Condition will Receive "data"

         // Add Object
         if (i == 0)
             [_orderType1 addObject:data];
         else if (i == 1)
             [_orderType2 addObject:data];
         else if (i == 2)
             [_orderType3 addObject:data];
         else if (i == 3)
             [_orderType4 addObject:data];
         else 
             [_orderType5 addObject:data];
    } 

    _allData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_orderType1, _orderType2, _orderType3, _orderType4, _orderType5, nil];
```

Result of this code is worked and Correct. but I want to name of _orderType with index i.

example : in loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < orderCount; i++)    // orderCount is count of orderType(count = 5)
{
      // Do something about condition to get Data...
      // ... This Condition will Receive "data"

      // Add Object
      [_orderType[i] addObject:data]       
}
```

How to Resolve it or I can't Resolve it in this condition.

Thank you and sorry about my mistake.

Comment: Have you thought of using NSMutableDictionary for *allData instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
self.orderType1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.orderType2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.orderType3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.orderType4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.orderType5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.allData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.orderType1, self.orderType2, self.orderType3, self.orderType4, self.orderType5, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < orderCount; i++) {
    [self.allData[i] addObject:data];
}
```

You probably want to avoid using syntax like `_orderType1` because that is accessing the variable directly, instead of using a getter or setter. Instead, use `self.orderType1`.